# leave the caption empty

Tags: floats, captions

I have figure with multiple figures (top, bottom). I want to use (a,b,..) for multiple figures. but all my figures have titles on, I believe that putting caption for (a) and (b) is not necessary.

Can I leave the caption for a, b empty and put only one caption for the whole figure?
such as:
(a) empty caption
(b) empty caption
Figure 1. The speed of Method1 at (a), and Method2 at (b).

Comment: like `\subcaption{}`?

Comment: yes I want to leave the subcaption empty ?

Comment: how is thios your question realted to the previus https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491006/reference-figure-with-multiple-figures?

Answer (score 2):

This is the memoir way of doing it, but the principle should hold for other ways.

Just leave the caption part of the argument to the subfloat empty, and only fill in the whole figure caption!

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subtop[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subtop[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{Whole figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]